# GCP- Alert for adding new user or service account to a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-compute-engine, query, google-iam

I want to create an alert in my project in GCP that lets me know when a new user or service account is added to the project. I understand I need to use Logs Explorer and run a query but I am not sure what query to run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a log-based metric for the api call for the operations you're interested in. In this case, for example, for service account creation:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts

You could create a metric to look for any operations that create, update etc.